# Using variable for DataTableReader "datatable" name

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm a bit of a noob so please be nice. I've searched google/stackoverflow/everywhere else and haven't found any answer but I'm not sure if I am even using correct terms.

A bit of background first:

I have made a webpage which displays mysql data on a dashboard. Everything is working correctly.

Each "tile" on the dashboard has different data displayed with google charts made with mysql queries in my aspx page. Each tile also has a "refresh" button to be able to run the query again to update the chart.

The refresh button has the same class for each tile but a unique ID:

```
<input type="button" id="DailyTotal" class="rebind"/>
```

Clicking this runs a javascript function that does the following:

- Calls iHttpHandler with AJAX to read the DataTable and retrieve new query data
- Formats data into JSON
- Redraws the chart

This is all working correctly so far.

Now here's my question:

How do I pass the ID of the tile along with the AJAX call to the iHttpHandler so that I can select the correct query to run on the codebehind?

The ID of each tile is the same name as the corresponding DataTable.

At the moment my code is like this:

```
private static DataTable ProgrammingTable(string chart)
        {
        var rand = new System.Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        var dt = new DataTable();

        DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(Dashboard.DailyTotal());
        try
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Is there any way that I can make the "DailyTotal())" a variable so that I can have one piece of code that's able to update each tile?

I've tried doing this by using an ASP hidden field to pass the ID but I'm still unsure of how to structure the code so that it knows to use the value of the variable as the name for the DataTable and not think that the variable name is the DataTable name.

This is what I tried on my 
ASPX page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ChartID" runat="server" value=""/>
```

JS:

```
var chartName = $(this).attr("id");
$("input[id=ChartID]").val(chartName);
```

Codebehind:

```
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        HiddenField ChartID = (HiddenField)page.FindControl("ChartID");
        var aa = ChartID.Value;
```

Then I tried doing this:

```
            DataTableReader reader = new DataTableReader(Dashboard.aa());
```

But it obviously just looks for a DataTable named aa.

The only solution I can think of is giving each tile its own ajax call and iHttpHandler but that's obviously not preferable.

Please help and please let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  +1 for a detailed and well thought out and documented question, and a valiant effort for a "noob" - your word, not mine :)

Comment: It occurred to me that the title of the question might be a little misleading, or not really address the crux of this issue.  I was going to offer an edit myself, but will leave that decision up to you.  I would consider your real issues to be... 1. passing a string from client to server using (jQuery?) ajax call and ASP.NET WebMethod(?), 2. calling a method based on a string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to give you a more in depth answer when I have time, but I've been meaning to respond to your question since you posted it, just busy.  Quickly though I will say one approach is to use a switch statement or if/else blocks to call different methods based on the ID you get from the client.  This is a brute force method and therefore not very elegant, nor does it scale well or lend itself to manageable code.

A better approach might be to use reflection, since your IDs match the method name you want to call.

I will add details when I have time, but you can start your own research with that maybe, as you seem quite competent for a self-proclaimed noob.

As for passing the ID from the client to the server via `asp:HiddenField`, that will not work because a synchronous post-back is required in order to update the server's view of the value that you just set on the client.  Think of the hidden field sort of like a mailbox that you just put a letter in, and then the ajax call is like you just made a telephone call to the letter's recipient, but the postman (post back) hasn't even come to pick the letter up yet.  This analogy starts to fall apart after that, and is not perfect but hopefully it sheds some light.  So what you want to do is pass the ID To the server in the ajax call itself. This will become the parameter value (`chart`) that the sever side method receives.  If you have multiple pieces of data to pass to the server you can serialize all the data as JSON and pass a single object to the server where it can be deserialized.  Again, I will provide details and an example when I have time and something more than a phone with which to respond.  Can you please post the details of the ajax call itself so I can try to tailor the example to your code?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I really appreciate it :) 

I'll start doing some research on reflection - that's just the sort of clue I needed. I just felt like I was constantly googling the wrong terms to find what I am after. 

Here is the JS code which has the ajax call: http://pastebin.com/fMFn7iZN (was too big to fit into comment)

Comment: @Bryan Just wanted to reply to your comment quickly.  I will expand on my answer when I can.  I'm kind of surprised nobody else responded, which is part of the reason I felt obligated to post something, even if it's vague right now.  If you leave this unanswered it will likely get more views, as people tend to avoid answering questions already have an accepted answered.  I know what you mean about not knowing exactly where to start on a new topic.  And I should say that reflection is not the holy grail, there is a performance hit associated with it.  So you have to weigh the pros and cons.

Comment: Hi Eric, I just wanted to thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I now have it working by sending the string with the ajax call and by using a IF/ELSE statement within the handler. 

I really appreciate the help. :)